# Is the whole ethereum's source code stored in its clients?

Tags: private-blockchain, clients

I would like to edit the ethereum's source code and add it some improvements. I could find only ethereum clients source code (in java,cpp, python and go). is the whole ethereum's code stored in its clients?

Does it enable to create private ethereum network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ethereum clients are the implementation of the erhereum protocol (it's said [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)) so they are basically the "ethereum source codes". you just need to fork/download the repos and you're set.

And yes you can make your private network using these clients (go ethereum specifically because that's the version i use)

All the steps are shown in this [wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster). Good luck with your improvements!